# NameError on Script & DB Insert

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python

I am trying to use the Python script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23665826/1901781) for my own purposes. I'm no Python bloke, so hopefully someone can see what I have wrong. Is it an indent error?

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    csv_doc.write( ouput_to_csv.join("\n") );
NameError: name 'ouput_to_csv' is not defined`

Secondly, this script creates a CSV. I'd like to skip this step and write the data directly to a table in my database with MySQLdb. Is this possible?

```
# import the standard libraries you'll need
import os # https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html
import re # https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

# this function will walk your directories and output a list of file paths
def getFilePaths(directory):
    file_paths = []
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            file_paths.append(filepath)
    return file_paths

audio_file_paths = getFilePaths("Z:\Dropbox\Apps\DirScan\files")
output_to_csv = [];

for audio_file in audio_file_paths:
    base_path, fname = os.path.split(audio_file) 

    reg_ex = re.compile("^(.*) - (.*) - (.*).mp3$");

    # now apply the compiled regex to each path
    name_components = reg_ex.match(fname);

    output_to_csv.append("{0},{1}".format(name_components.join(","), base_path));

#create the file, making sure the location is writeable
csv_doc = open("database.csv", "w");

# now join all the rows with line breaks and write the compiled text to the file
csv_doc.write( ouput_to_csv.join("\n") ); 

#close  your new database
csv_doc.close()
```

Background is that I want to import audiofiles in a folder into a database, using the regex. Format is `Artist - Title - Other info.mp3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you write `ouput_to_csv` that must be `output_to_csv` you omit `t`

Comment: Ah cool thanks. I fixed that. Now I get `Z:\Dropbox\Apps\DirScan>c:\python27\python.exe "test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    csv_doc.write( output_to_csv.join("\n") );
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'`

Comment: Yes, because that's not how you join things in Python. List objects don't have a `join` method. You want `'\n'.join(output_to_csv)`

Comment: as mentioned in above you must use another format of join !

Comment: OK I updated line 31 with `csv_doc.write( '\n'.join(output_to_csv) );
` and the script runs without error. But the csv generated is empty. I have one MP3 in the dir named `1TrakMind - ModeMusic Session 01 - 201403`.

Comment: i think this its better to ask another question !