# Write Folder Contents to CSV with Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to use the Python script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23665826/1901781) for my own purposes. I'm no Python bloke, so hopefully someone can see what I have wrong.

The below script doesn't error out. My CSV is created with no values. Do I have a join problem? I'm expecting to have data written to the CSV.

```
# import the standard libraries you'll need
import os # https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html
import re # https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

# this function will walk your directories and output a list of file paths
def getFilePaths(directory):
    file_paths = []
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            file_paths.append(filepath)
    return file_paths

audio_file_paths = getFilePaths("Z:\Dropbox\Apps\DirScan\files")
output_to_csv = [];

for audio_file in audio_file_paths:
    base_path, fname = os.path.split(audio_file) 

    reg_ex = re.compile("^(.*) - (.*) - (.*).mp3$");

    # now apply the compiled regex to each path
    name_components = reg_ex.match(fname);

    output_to_csv.append("{0},{1}".format(",".join(name_components), base_path));

#create the file, making sure the location is writeable
csv_doc = open("database.csv", "w");

# now join all the rows with line breaks and write the compiled text to the file
csv_doc.write( '\n'.join(output_to_csv) );


#close  your new database
csv_doc.close()
```

Comment: do you want to find the name of songs?

Comment: Yeah. Ideally MP3 tag like eyeD3 would work. But the file names follow a strict format, so this table/CSV can be extracted from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 29, in <module>
    output_to_csv.append("{0},{1}".format(",".join(name_components), base_path));
TypeError
```

Because `name_components` is a regex `Match` object, which doesn't work as an argument to `join`. You need to replace:

```
",".join(name_components)
```

With:

```
",".join(name_components.groups())
```

After making that change I can see the CSV file gets written to correctly.

One other minor point: you don't need a semicolon at the end of a line in python.

Comment: Thanks and thanks! FYI I had to change the backslashes to forward slashes in the file path too.